# IllegalStateException: getInputStream() is not available. Is this a reentrant call?

Tags: java, android, http

I'm creating a class for making the download of an item. I'm using the following method for connect and retrieve the download info:

```
public mDownload(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
    this.url = new URL(url);
}

private void connect() throws IOException {
    connection = url.openConnection();
    date = connection.getDate();
--> expiration = connection.getExpiration();
    length = connection.getContentLength();
    lastModified = connection.getLastModified();
}
```

But I have some reports of force crashes at the `-->` line:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInputStream() is not available. Is this a reentrant call?
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:524)
        at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:464)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldDate(URLConnection.java:548)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFieldDate(HttpURLConnection.java:702)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getExpiration(URLConnection.java:426)
```

Why is this error happening and how can I avoid it? Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't help much but I wasn't able to reproduce this Exception on ICS 4.0.4 (SGS2) at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this commit](http://gitorious.org/ginger/libcore/commit/c6dae581716b9362a5c7f166c80a7f2b46ed1124/diffs?diffmode=sidebyside&fragment=1), this may be a poor exception message.  It may be that the response failed to return any data.  You could confirm by monitoring the actual network traffic.